# What is the appropriate way to take in files that have a filename with a timestamp in it?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, filenames

What is the appropriate way to take in files that have a filename with a timestamp in it and read properly?
One way I'm thinking of so far is to take these filenames into one single text file to read all at once.
For example, filenames such as

```
1573449076_1570501819_file1.txt
1573449076_1570501819_file2.txt
1573449076_1570501819_file3.txt
```

Go into a file named filenames.txt

Then something like

```
with open('/Documents/filenames.txt', 'r') as f:
for item in f:
    if item.is_file():
        file_stat = os.stat(item)
        item = item.replace('\n', '')
        print("Fetching {}".format(convert_times(file_stat)))
```

My question is how would I go about this where I can properly read the names in the text file given that they have timestamps in the actual names? Once figuring that out I can convert them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to get the timestamps from the file names, assuming that they all use the same naming convention, you can do so like this:

```py
import glob
import os
from datetime import datetime

# Grab all .txt files in the specified directory
files = glob.glob("<path_to_dir>/*.txt")

for file in files:
    file = os.path.basename(file)
    # Check that it contains an underscore
    if not '_' in file:
        continue
    # Split the file name using the underscore as the delimiter
    stamps = file.split('_')
    # Convert the epoch to a legible string
    start = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(stamps[0])).strftime("%c")
    end = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(stamps[1])).strftime("%c")
    # Consume the data
    print(f"{start} - {end}")
    ...
```

You'll want to add some error checking and handling; for instance, if the first or second index in the `stamps` array isn't a parsable int, this will fail.

Comment: The timestamps are in the actual names so this was not a case of using datetime to give the times of when the files were made which made it tricky for me. This was really helpful